# MSSQL Server 2008R2 Time stamped cumulative data - interval computation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am a novice at SQL.

We have a time stamped cumulative count data available on daily and hourly basis
Keeping the problem limited to daily data.

Sample Data:

```
2008-01-01   123
2008-01-02   135
2008-01-03   150
2008-01-04   160
2008-01-05   170
```

Output Data needed

```
Year Month CountOnDate1  CountOnDate2  CountOnDate3 CountOnDate4  CountOnDate5  ..so on

2008  JAN     0              12           15           10              10
```

Is there an efficient and straight forward way of doing it on MSSQL Server2008R2.
All methods I have tried to so far are way too slow.
I have tried CTE, Pivoting.
There is restriction not to have a table to store data that can be computed.
Hope I do not sound too naive

Looking for some guidance.
Regards
Ajay

Adding more information
My problems are two step
1. To calculate the difference between counts on two consecutive dates
2. And to pivot the difference based on day of the month into columns

Step 1: I have a view that uses scalar function to fetch next record and create a difference values

```
View 1: 
Sample Data:
    Col1         Col2   Col3
    2008-01-01   123     0
    2008-01-02   135     12
    2008-01-03   150     15
    2008-01-04   160     10
    2008-01-05   170     10
```

Step 2:
Create a cross tab pivot from View 1

```
SELECT     * FROM         (SELECT    MONth(Col1) AS MonthNumber, 'D' + CONVERT(nvarchar(5), DAY(Col1))  AS ConsumptionDay, Col3) AS Sample_Value, ltrim(CONVERT(nvarchar(3), Col1, 107)) AS ConsumptionMonth,  ltrim('Y' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4), Col1, 120)) AS ConsumptionYear
FROM         View 1) src 
PIVOT (sum(Sample_Value) FOR ConsumptionDay IN ([D1], [D2], [D3], [D4], [D5], [D6], [D7], [D8], [D9], [D10], [D11], [D12], 
                  [D13], [D14], [D15], [D16], [D17], [D18], [D19], [D20], [D21], [D22], [D23], [D24], [D25], [D26], [D27], [D28], [D29], [D30], [D31])) AS pvT
```

I do believe, I am doing something wrong
Hope someone can help
Ajay

Comment: the keyword here is PIVOT in the sql syntax http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What have you actually tried? The speed of your queries could be due to indexing, not the way you are pivoting your data.